# Why is this Compliance Screening page shown while signing into iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have created a new account for someone else to add me as "developer" role in their iTunesConnect account. As soon as I accepted their invitation in the mail this is shown:

[image]

Is this mandatory? My friend who created a similar account did not get into any page like this.

If I press Cancel, I'm redirected to the login page.

Comment: I'm getting same as well